# React - State is not updating on scroll event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Short overview :
I have 2 components one is parent and another one is child. child component is showing list of items, which shows 5 items at a time and when user scrolls down and reaches to the bottom , the component makes api call to fetch more 5 data.

Brief :

Code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Row = (data) => {
  const {
    data: item,
  } = data;

  const {
    name,
  } = item;


  return (
    <div className={styles.recentCard}>
      <div>
      <p>name</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const EmptyRow = () => (
  <div className={styles.loading}>
    {/* <ClipLoadingComponent /> */}
    <p> Loading ...</p>
    {/* <LoadingComponent /> */}
  </div>
);

const RecentResponses = () => {
  const [recentCandidateResponses, setRecentCandidateResponses] = useState([]);
  const [startPage, setStartPage] = useState(1);
  const [endPage, setEndPage] = useState(4);
  const [isFetchRecentResponsesProcessing, setisFetchRecentResponsesProcessing] = useState(false);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('startPage Changed :::', startPage);
    console.log('endPage Changed :::', endPage);

  }, [startPage, endPage]);


  const fetchRecentResponses = (newStart, newEnd) => {
    try {
    console.log('fetchRecentResponses event')
      CandidateActions.fetchCandidateRecentResponse(newStart, newEnd);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error loading more items:', err);
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    console.log('Click event')
    // fetchRecentResponses();

    const container = containerRef.current;
    if
    (
      convertToDecimal(
        container.scrollHeight,
      ) - convertToDecimal(
        container.scrollTop,
      ) === convertToDecimal(
        container.clientHeight,
      )
    ) {
      if (!isFetchRecentResponsesProcessing) {
        console.log(`Start page : ${startPage} | End Page : ${endPage}`)
        const newStart = startPage + 4; 
        const newEnd = endPage + 5;
        setStartPage(newStart);
        setEndPage(newEnd);

        fetchRecentResponses(newStart, newEnd);
      }
    }
  };

  const onChangeCandidateStore = (candidateStoreData) => {
    const {
      recentResponses,
      isFetchRecentResponsesProcessing, //eslint-disable-line
    } = candidateStoreData;
    setRecentCandidateResponses(recentResponses);
    setisFetchRecentResponsesProcessing(isFetchRecentResponsesProcessing);
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('PAGE IS Loaded');
    fetchRecentResponses(startPage, endPage);
    CandidateStore.listen(onChangeCandidateStore); // listens for store change
    containerRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      containerRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);



  return (
    <div className={styles.recentResponsesContainer}>
      <h4 className={styles.recentResponsePanelTitle}>Candidate Response</h4>
      <button onClick={handleScroll}>Click here</button>
      <div
        ref={containerRef}
        style={{
          height: '62rem',
          overflowY: !isFetchRecentResponsesProcessing ? 'auto' : 'hidden',
        }}
      >
        {recentCandidateResponses.map(item => (
          <Row data={item} />
        ))}
        {isFetchRecentResponsesProcessing && (
          <div style={{ position: 'relative', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
            <EmptyRow />
          </div>
        )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecentResponses;
```

On first load I get value as expected that is 1 and 4 for startPage and endPage respectively and same for first scroll that is 5 and 9. But When I try to do third scroll the value of startPage and endPage remains 1 and 4 resulting increment updates to 5 and 9 again where it has to be 10 and 13.
I am stuck here , Please help me in this matter.
Thanks in advance